# 引数が文字列型と、戻り値が文字列型を要素に持つ配列型　処理方法

Tags: java

ユーザー定義メソッドを作成したいのですが、
メソッドの呼び出し側の記述が、どうしたらよいのか分からなくて困っています。
また、メソッド定義も合っているのか分からないため、教えて頂きたいです。

以下詳細、、、

・引数→文字列型
・戻り値→文字列型を要素に持つ配列型
・処理内容
→3人分のプロフィール情報を、それぞれの配列で作成する。
そして、引数として受け取ったIDの値と同じIDを持つ配列を、戻り値として返す。
メソッドを作成したら、メソッドを呼び出し、
その戻り値に格納された要素をそれぞれ表示する。
このとき、表示する要素は反復処理によって順番に指定するものとし、IDの値については表示しないものとする。

//コード

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 

/** 

@author otoja
*/
public class kadai extends HttpServlet { 
/** 
Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> 
methods. 

@param request servlet request 
@param response servlet response 
@throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs 
@throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
*/ 
String[] profile(String key){
    String [][] profile_list={
        {"ID:123456","1993/11/8生まれ","東京都練馬区"},
        {"ID:987654","2012/3/14生まれ","東京都三鷹市"},
        {"ID:192837","2017/6/17生まれ","東京都中野区"} }; 
    if(key.equals(profile_list[1])){
        return profile_list[1]; 
    }else if(key.equals(profile_list[0])){
        return profile_list[0];
    }else{
        return profile_list[2];
    }
}
```

上記で合っていますでしょうか？
また、prosessRequest以降の呼び出し側は、どのように記述すればよいでしょうか？ 
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

「表示」というのはおそらくHTMLとして表示するということだと推測しますが、実装例を提示するには詳細な入力仕様および出力仕様（フォーマット）に関する情報が不足しているため、ひとまず標準出力に1行ずつ表示する例を示します。

質問をするときは最低限のマナーとして、開発環境および実行環境に関する詳しい情報（OS、JDKのバージョンなど）を記載するようにしてください。新しいバージョンのJava言語仕様では、コードをより簡潔に記述できる機能などが追加されていますが、古いJDKでは使用できません。結果として環境に関する情報は回答のしやすさに影響します。

[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://view-source:http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html)

まずは**配列の配列**（**ジャグ配列**）のインデックス指定方法に関する文法を学習してください。

配列などのコレクションから要素を総当たりで**線形検索**する場合、ループを使えば一般化できます。要素数がコンパイル時に決まらず、実行時にしか分からないケースにも容易に対応できます。条件分岐だと要素数が増えたときにコードのメンテナンス性が悪くなります。

ただし検索時間は *O*(*n*) で要素数に線形比例します。巨大なデータベースをメモリ上に載せる場合は通例検索効率のよいMapやHashMapなどを使います。

```
/**
 * キーに該当するプロファイルを返す。
 * @param key 検索キー。
 * @return 見つかったプロファイル。該当しなければ null を返す。
 */
static String[] searchProfile(String key) {
    final String[][] profileList = {
        {"ID:123456", "1993/11/8生まれ", "東京都練馬区"},
        {"ID:987654", "2012/3/14生まれ", "東京都三鷹市"},
        {"ID:192837", "2017/6/17生まれ", "東京都中野区"},
    };
    // 線形検索。検索時間は要素数に線形比例する。
    for (int i = 0; i < profileList.length; ++i) {
        if (key.equals(profileList[i][0])) {
            return profileList[i];
        }
    }
    return null; // 該当なし。
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String[] profile = searchProfile("ID:123456");
    if (profile == null) {
        System.out.println("Not found.");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < profile.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(profile[i]);
    }
}
```

ちなみに、質問文中の "processRequest" というのは何者ですか？
おそらく以下のように HttpServlet.doGet(), HttpServlet.doPost() 内で呼び出すユーザー定義メソッドのことだと推測しますが、メソッドの中身をどう記述するかは、どういうサーブレットを実装するのか、ということに依存します。HTMLを出力するだけであれば、doGet()をオーバーライドします。サーブレットの実装はタイトル（本質問の主題）と乖離する内容になるため、質問を混ぜずにトピックを分けるか、質問自体を適切に修正・追記してください。

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO: クライアントのリクエストに応じた処理を実装。
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

なお、Javaの慣習ではクラス名の先頭を大文字にします。**Javadocコメント**についても学習してください。

Answer (score 1):

```
if(key.equals(profile_list[1])){
    return profile_list[1]; 
}else if(key.equals(profile_list[0])){
    return profile_list[0];
}else{
    return profile_list[2];
}
```

このif文では、String型のkeyとString[]型のprofile_list[1]/profile_list[0]を比較しているため、常にprofile_list[2]が返ります。

単純に実装するとしたら次にようになるでしょうか。

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * @author otoja
 */
public class kadai extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        if (id == null) {
            return;
        }
        String[] profile = this.profile(id);
        if (profile != null) {
            response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            for (int i = 1; i < profile.length; i++) {
                response.getWriter().println(profile[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    String[] profile(String key) {
        String[][] profile_list = {
                { "ID:123456", "1993/11/8生まれ", "東京都練馬区" },
                { "ID:987654", "2012/3/14生まれ", "東京都三鷹市" },
                { "ID:192837", "2017/6/17生まれ", "東京都中野区" }
        };
        for (String[] profile : profile_list) {
            if (profile[0].equals(key)) {
                return profile;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```